# Excel append update fails with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I fetch data from URL and try to append the rows to the existing excel file with following code..

```
  if (file.exists()) {
                in=new FileInputStream(new File(path));

                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
                sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                in.close();
            } else {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                sheet = workbook.createSheet();
                row = sheet.createRow(0);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("keyTerm");
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue("username");
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Text");
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue("Timestamp");
            }
```

and then

```
int count = sheet.getLastRowNum();    
for (int i = 0; i < tweets.length(); i++) {
                        tweet = tweets.getJSONObject(i);
                        count++;
                        row = sheet.createRow(count);
                        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(term);
                        row.createCell(1)
                                .setCellValue(tweet.getString("from_user"));
                        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(
                                tweets.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
                        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(
                                tweet.getString("created_at"));
    }
```

The code works well for the new files but fails for the existing files to append even when I have opened the file in append mode for write.

```
out = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `write` method does not write only the new additions that you have made to the spreadsheet.  It writes the *entire* workbook to the output stream.  So if you attempt to append the entire new workbook to the old workbook, I can see that it will not do what you think.

I've never appended to an existing file when writing out a workbook to a file.  You should always open the stream in (the default) overwrite mode, so the entire workbook (and nothing but the entire workbook) goes to the stream and to the destination file.

```
out = new FileOutputStream(file);  // or new FileOutputStream(file, false);
```

Your current code only works when the file doesn't exist yet because there is nothing to append to.  In summary, don't append; overwrite (or write to a different file).

Comment: thanks. but, isnt this costly on a longer run, say I have 30K records and adding hardly 10-12 records

Comment: Yes, but it can't be helped.  The `write` method is the only method to output the spreadsheet, and it writes everything.